# name can only contain URL-friendly characters

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-4, npm-install, gulp-sass

I was trying to install package.json with npm init to install bootstrap in my folder but i am getting the error.

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --save
```

I am new to this i can't exactly figure what i am doing wrong.
I was following a tutorial whose link i'll attach along with screenshot of my console.

[this the tutorial link](https://coursetro.com/posts/design/72/Installing-B)

[image: this is the screenshot]

Comment: I had the same problem. Then I realized that I never finish the npm init properly.

Comment: Semi-unrelated but this error is also thrown (still aka nowadays) if a _scoped_ `package` in your `package.json` is missing the apparently mandatory `/`. As in, you'll get this error if your trying to list e.g. `@my-nice-package` as a `dep`/dependency. This should be `@my-nice-package/some-subpackage` since the whole point of having scoped packages is to 'subclass'/'subpackage' so to speak.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was getting the same problem but I changed `package-name` first name was like:

```
My Folder Name
```

I changed it to

```
my-folder-name
```

with no spaces & no capital letters. It solved the problem for me.
Happy coding

Answer (score 14):

npm init is actually creating the package.json file and setting the characteristics of the project(It has no relation with bootstrap). So, in the field package name, you have to enter the name of your project (you have now entered the npm install bootstrap command) or you can just press enter if the name displayed in bracket is enough. Complete the npm init processs by setting all characteristics of project.

As next step, you can do `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --save`. It'll work

Comment: I tried that but it says "Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters."

Comment: What did you enter in package name field?

Comment: Hey @SurajKumar! We are Facing a similar problem here. What did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 13):

Deleting the lock-file and running `npm i` again solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just hit enter and cycle through all the options. You don't type in the npm install  until after you have finished init.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue while installing the json-server ...but got resolved actually the problem is not with the folder name....so, there is two way to sort this problem one by ---- after npm init press 5-8 times enter or u can directly use (npm init -y) both will work fine
Happy coding

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not only DELETE package-lock.json in main folder but also find (whit this command `find node_modules/ -iname *-lock*`) and delete all '-lock' files in node_modules then run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you  are typing in the  right place, `npm  init` and then hit enter/return a few  times until you are at a prompt starting  with `C:\Users`  if you     are  in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem when installing sass, because I watched some tutorials on YT where they instructed to use Live Sass Compiler, so I had to change some settings for saving the file. Then I uninstalled it, go through the traditional process of

```
npm init
npm install node-sass --save-dev
npm run compile:sass
```

and .....BAMMMM!!!! It worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Press a few enter that will help you get out of `npm init`. then type the `npm install` comment. This worked for me.