# what is the correct sentence for installing create-react-app on MacOs

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npx

I tried to install create-react-app. I wrote npm init in terminal, then npm install create-react-app and it says the following: **"Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters"**.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107455/name-can-only-contain-url-friendly-characters

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```