# React Native error in dependencies : name can only contain URL-friendly characters

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, react-native, dependencies

I've got this issue : each time I try to npm install something (or yarn), I got this error :

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "@types/react-navigation/native" of package "@types/react-navigation/native@^6.0.10": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
```

Does anyone know what to do? I can't just deleate "@types/react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10", or another error will arrive.
Here is my json :

```
{
  "name": "projtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~11.2.3",
    "expo-cli": "^5.4.3",
    "expo-constants": "^13.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "^3.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-web-webview": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.18",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: this works for me
[delete package-lock.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54872219/7864983)