# npm throws npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME npm ERR! Invalid package name "Authorization Error"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start

I just installed node.js and tried to start with a react project. But every npm command ("npm install..." , "npm start" , "npm update -g") throws me:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "Authorization Error" of package "Authorization Error@*": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
```

I guess its caused by the space in the package name "Authorization Error", but I cant find this package in the nodejs files or a package.json which includes this package. I reinstalled node.js again, but I keep getting this error message on all npm installs. Here is the complete error log.

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.5.1
2 info using node@v18.16.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\triroe\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\triroe\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load Completed in 16ms
16 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 16ms
17 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
19 verbose title npm update
20 verbose argv "update" "--global"
21 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 2ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 6ms
23 timing npm:load:display Completed in 7ms
24 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\triroe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-26T07_32_21_557Z-
25 verbose logfile C:\Users\triroe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-26T07_32_21_557Z-debug-0.log
26 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 11ms
27 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
28 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 1ms
29 timing npm:load Completed in 41ms
30 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 timing idealTree:init Completed in 10ms
35 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
36 silly idealTree buildDeps
37 silly fetch manifest node-red@*
38 http fetch GET 200 https://npm.cicd.qibb.com/node-red 460ms (cache miss)
39 silly placeDep ROOT node-red@ OK for:  want: *
40 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 476ms
41 timing idealTree:node_modules/node-red Completed in 0ms
42 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 478ms
43 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
44 timing idealTree Completed in 492ms
45 timing command:update Completed in 504ms
46 verbose stack Error: Invalid package name "Authorization Error" of package "Authorization Error@*": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
46 verbose stack     at invalidPackageName (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-package-arg\lib\npa.js:111:15)
46 verbose stack     at Result.setName (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-package-arg\lib\npa.js:158:11)
46 verbose stack     at new Result (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-package-arg\lib\npa.js:147:10)
46 verbose stack     at Function.resolve (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-package-arg\lib\npa.js:59:15)
46 verbose stack     at pickManifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\lib\index.js:88:20)
46 verbose stack     at module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\lib\index.js:187:16)
46 verbose stack     at RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:119:22)
46 verbose stack     at async [nodeFromEdge] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1059:19)
46 verbose stack     at async [buildDepStep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:929:11)
46 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:207:7)
47 verbose cwd C:\Users\triroe\Documents\Workspace\React\udemy-react-project
48 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
49 verbose node v18.16.0
50 verbose npm  v9.5.1
51 error code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
52 error Invalid package name "Authorization Error" of package "Authorization Error@*": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
53 verbose exit 1
54 timing npm Completed in 598ms
55 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1682494341642
56 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1682494341649
57 verbose code 1
58 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I also followed solutions of similiar problems, by "npm cache clean –force" followed by deleting the package from package.json, but how mentioned I cant find the package in my node installation files.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107455/name-can-only-contain-url-friendly-characters

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not on a proxy network. Usually such networks need a username and password in order to run commands that require access to the internet.

Comment: As I know, I'm not using a proxy. Also couldn't find anything in my settings.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I was using a proxy, which which was listed as registry in `npm config list --json`. I setted it to default by `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`.